# time different betwen two columns in mysql higher than xx days

Tags: mysql, datetime

Please help me:

I have two columns in mysql table - date1 (datetime) and date2 (datetime)

I need find rows where difference between these two days is higher the 14 days.

I tried: select * from table where timediff(`date1` - `date2`) as days > 14
it does not work

Thanky you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(date1,date2)) > 14;
```